# Language/Programming term for paired delimiters

Tags: language-design, parsing

Can someone help me find the language and/or programming term for delimiters (?) that must be paired?

Quotes, parenthesis, angle-brackets, square-brackets, etc. are often used to symbolize these constructs.

Is there a terminology distinction when the begin/end symbols are identical (such as some quotes) and when they are distinct (open/close brackets)?

Is there a term to describe the contents of such pairs?

I am writing an script that needs to be aware of delimiter pairs (?).  I would prefer to use existing (but as of this writing unknown to me) terminology for this concept to make my code content clear to others without coining new terminology.

Comment: This can be a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893722/why-the-inline-string-block-in-ruby-is-named-eos/14894221#14894221 Maybe you would look into grammars that describe languages.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: @User: I don't see how that applies here.

Comment: `Is there a term to describe the contents of such pairs?` -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(programming)

Comment: I've always said, for example, `"Hello, world!"` is a string that is *delimited* by quote marks. You could also say that the initial `"` symbol *introduces* the string and the final `"` *terminates* the string... if you forget the closing quote then it is called a *non-terminated string* or *malformed string* or you could just keep looking for the closing `"` and eventually give up, saying `unexpected end of file`

Comment: @RobertHarvey The comment mentioned this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document "Heredoc" is another name. And additionally in Mime (e-mails) it is called "boundary".

Comment: @user: Doesn't seem relevant.  Heredoc appears to be a way to close out multiline documents passed as input to a program, and doesn't have much to do with delimiter pairs like braces (except insofar as it has a passing resemblance).

Comment: In any case, it's called a "code block."  Wikipedia calls it a "block" because `<tag>content</tag>` is technically not code.  if you want your users to understand, you can't use any other term; all of the other possible candidates are obscure parser terminology.

Comment: "Bracket delimiter" is a tautology.  You already told us it is both a bracket and a delimiter in your question.  "Block delimiters" (suggested as an alternative term in the Wikipedia article you linked) is a better definition.

Comment: I call them grouping delimiters. Not to be confused with separators.

Comment: @shawnhcorey: Unique term that conveys its function.  Good one.

Comment: Parsing (in general, theoretical) hove some context where delimiters (blocks etc) aren't normally paired. Example: coments or other operations to the end of line, or Python blocks (semantically block exist, but lexically can say no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia, here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter, says

Delimiters can be broken down into:

```
Field and record delimiters; and
Bracket delimiters.

Bracket delimiters (also block delimiters, region delimiters or balanced delimiters) 
mark both the start and end of a region of text.
```

I don't know of any formal term used in grammar programs (i.e. parser generator software), as you usually just put both the tokens of a bracket delimiter together somewhere on the same grammar rule definition, thus they both have to be present for the rule to apply, no other special pairwise matching is called out.

Answer (score 2):

"Matching delimiters" refers to the pair, as in "the text between matching delimiters is automatically highlighted." Your sample

> I am writing an script that needs to be aware of delimiter pairs

becomes

> I am writing a script that needs to be aware of matching delimiters.

Also, "the matching delimiter" works when you're talking about one of them and want to refer to the other one. I don't know of any word that captures the distinction between the two delimiters being the same symbol or not.